# Facebook Messanger pages_messaging permission OAuthException

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I have created a messenger app that was approved with the pages_messaging permission.

Even though it was approved and the app is live, when I try to post messages it keeps on saying:
`{"error":{"message":"(#10) Cannot message users who are not admins, developers or testers of the app until pages_messaging permission is reviewed and the app is live.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"FuSikGYV3dH"}}`

- The app is public - I have managed to find it.
- The app is approved
- The pages_messaging permission was granted.

So why it keeps on throwing this error?

General app permissions:
[image: General app permissions]

messaging permissions:
[image: messaging permissions]

Any ideas what's wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Double-check your app id/secret. If that’s not it, file a bug report and ask them to look into it, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks @CBroe.
I've reported - will update about the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check and put your app LIVE under developer Dashboard -> App Review!